# with root cause javax.el.ELException:

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have the following code in my jsp page

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="<c:if test="${fn:length(page.likes)}">display:none</c:if>" class="like">Like</a>&nbsp;
```

I am getting the following exception

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 1 of type class java.lang.Integer to class java.lang.Boolean
org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToBoolean(ELSupport.java:207)
org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:402)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
 <c:if test="${(fn:length(page.likes))==0}">   :)
```